How to ensure a job can only being executed once a time but restartable?
I set up a job and instance by a parameter, but I can only execute one time. How can i config a job to allow it being executed unlimited times but by given any time only one job is running no concurrency allowed.

Have you tried to use a JobParametersIncrementer ?

you could use a single thread task executor for your lob launcher.
  @Bean
  public JobLauncher jobLauncher() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(1);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(1);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("SingleThread-");
    executor.initialize();
    
    TaskExecutorJobLauncher jobLauncher = new TaskExecutorJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(executor);
    return jobLauncher;
  }

